# How to remove minimum weight edge from each node in a networkx graph

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have an undirected graph and I'm looking for a way to remove the minimum weight edge from every node. I tried several methods but they all seem to fail.

Comment: Welcome! Could you be more specific? since the graph is undirected the result is going to change according to the order in which you consider the nodes.

Comment: Hello, the graph is a complete graph consisting of 5 nodes each of them with a specific weight. I'm looking for a way to cut the minimum weight edge from each node. For example, I have 4 edges for each of the 5 nodes and I want to cut the lowest value one so every node will have 3 edges. I hope I make sense.

Comment: Suppose all the edge of minimum weight are incident to a node u. By taking a complete graph and just removing the minimum edge from each node, you end up with a graph disconnected. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry for not specifying earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a complete graph

```
>>> G = nx.complete_graph(n=5)
>>> for (u, v) in G.edges():
...     G.edges[u,v]['weight'] = random.randint(0,10)
```

To take the minimum weight edge incident to a node and then remove it you can do as follows.

```
>>> for u in G.nodes():
...     min_weight_edge = min(G.edges(u), key=lambda x: G.get_edge_data(x[0], x[1])["weight"])
...     G.remove_edge(*min_weight_edge)
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First create a complete graph with random weights:

```
g = nx.complete_graph(5)
for (u,v,w) in g.edges(data=True):
    w['weight'] = random.randint(0,10)
```

#### Option1: iterate over the nodes and remove the minimum weight edge.

```
for n in g.nodes():
    min_weight = (-1,-1,float("inf"))
    for e in g.edges(nbunch=n,data="weight"):
        #print(e)
        if min_weight[2] > e[2]:
            min_weight = e
    print(min_weight)
    g.remove_edge(min_weight[0], min_weight[1])
```

#### Option 2: remove edges in the end.

Only remove the edges in the end, checking if the edge is already in the list of edges to be removed.

```
edges_to_remove = set()
for n in g.nodes():
    min_weight = (-1,-1,float("inf"))
    for e in g.edges(nbunch=n,data="weight"):
        #print(e)
        if min_weight[2] > e[2]:
            min_weight = e
    
    if (min_weight[1],min_weight[0]) not in edges_to_remove:
        print(min_weight)
        edges_to_remove.add((min_weight[0],min_weight[1]))

for e in edges_to_remove:
    g.remove_edge(*e)
```

Notice that these two solutions yield different results:

- For the same graph:

Edges `(u,v,weight)` removed using Option 1:

```
(0, 3, 3)
(1, 2, 0)
(2, 3, 7)
(3, 1, 8)
(4, 1, 3)
```

Edges `(u,v,weight)` removed using Option 2:

```
(0, 3, 3)
(1, 2, 0)
(4, 1, 3)
```

- The first option removes the smallest weight edge for each node **depending on the order!**, i.e if the smallest weight edge has already been removed it will remove the next smallest weight edge. Will always remove as many edges as the number of nodes.
- The second option only removes the smallest weight edge for each node, i.e **if the smallest edge of a given node has already been removed it will not remove any edge**.